# tcmalloc: large alloc out of memory in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I see the following error in mongo 2.4.1 in linux

The error seems to be random , I am still not be able to track it to a specific query.

I did check for large skip values and didnt have any
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10136

One sample error is this it doesnt always fail after the same query

```
Fri Oct 11 15:16:52.780 [conn3429148] end connection 10.11.32.100:39274 (82 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:16:52.781 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.100:39276 #3429150 (83 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:16:53.661 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.98:59418 #3429151 (84 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:16:53.694 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.97:39813 #3429152 (85 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:06.811 [conn3429152] command xrr.$cmd command: { aggregate: "VehicleReview", pipeline: [ { $match: { make: "honda", model: "accord", year: "2013", moderationStatus: "STATUS_PASSED" } }, { $sort: { created: -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }, { $skip: 0 }, { $project: { _id: 1, _class: 1, author: 1, created: 1, updated: 1, title: 1, legacyId: 1, targetId: 1, text: 1, favoriteFeatures: 1, suggestedImprovements: 1, thumbsUpDownCounter: 1, ratings: 1, averageRating: 1, make: 1, model: 1, year: 1, subModels: 1, comments: { $ifNull: [ "$comments.comments", [ { moderationStatus: "STATUS_REJECTED" } ] ] } } }, { $unwind: "$comments" }, { $group: { _id: { _id: "$_id", _class: "$_class", author: "$author", created: "$created", updated: "$updated", title: "$title", targetId: "$targetId", text: "$text", legacyId: "$legacyId", favoriteFeatures: "$favoriteFeatures", suggestedImprovements: "$suggestedImprovements", thumbsUpDownCounter: "$thumbsUpDownCounter", ratings: "$ratings", averageRating: "$averageRating" }, commentsCount: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$comments.moderationStatus", "STATUS_REJECTED" ] }, 0, 1 ] } } } }, { $sort: { _id.created: -1 } } ] } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 107 locks(micros) r:22908773 reslen:1678 13115ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:06.811 [conn3428793] command xrr.$cmd command: { aggregate: "VehicleReview", pipeline: [ { $match: { make: "nissan", model: "altima", year: "2013", moderationStatus: "STATUS_PASSED" } }, { $group: { _id: { _id: "$all" }, averageRating: { $avg: "$averageRating" } } } ] } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 185 locks(micros) r:34276392 reslen:91 20340ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:06.811 [conn3429151] command xrr.$cmd command: { aggregate: "VehicleReview", pipeline: [ { $match: { make: "hyundai", model: "sonata", year: "2013", moderationStatus: "STATUS_PASSED" } }, { $sort: { c Oct 11 15:17:34.216 out of memory, printing stack and exiting:
0xdc7f71 0x6cd2ae 0x11fa48d 0xaf4a4f 0xaf0e8f 0xaf17ad 0xaf189f 0xaec46e 0xaec589 0xaea92e 0xaf82e8 0xaf8549 0xae3530 0xae39ef 0xaf0b2f 0xaf17c6 0xaf189f 0xb168c0 0x8a0ad2 0x8cd0ca
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdc7f71]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14my_new_handlerEv+0x3e) [0x6cd2ae]
/usr/bin/mongod(_Znwm+0x6d) [0x11fa48d]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZNSt6vectorIN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort9KeyAndDocESaIS2_EE7reserveEm+0x6f) [0xaf4a4f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort12populateTopKEv+0x6f) [0xaf0e8f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort8populateEv+0x2d) [0xaf17ad]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort3eofEv+0xf) [0xaf189f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSkip7skipperEv+0x6e) [0xaec46e]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSkip3eofEv+0x9) [0xaec589]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21DocumentSourceProject3eofEv+0xe) [0xaea92e]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceUnwind8lazyInitEv+0x138) [0xaf82e8]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceUnwind3eofEv+0x9) [0xaf8549]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup8populateEv+0x30) [0xae3530]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup3eofEv+0xf) [0xae39ef]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort11populateAllEv+0x2f) [0xaf0b2f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort8populateEv+0x46) [0xaf17c6]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort3eofEv+0xf) [0xaf189f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Pipeline3runERNS_14BSONObjBuilderERSs+0x1d0) [0xb168c0]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15PipelineCommand3runERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x132) [0x8a0ad2]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x3a) [0x8cd0ca]
Greated: -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }, { $skip: 0 }, { $project: { _id: 1, _class: 1, author: 1, created: 1, updated: 1, title: 1, legacyId: 1, targetId: 1, text: 1, favoriteFeatures: 1, suggestedImprovements: 1, thumbsUpDownCounter: 1, ratings: 1, averageRating: 1, make: 1, model: 1, year: 1, subModels: 1, comments: { $ifNull: [ "$comments.comments", [ { moderationStatus: "STATUS_REJECTED" } ] ] } } }, { $unwind: "$comments" }, { $group: { _id: { _id: "$_id", _class: "$_class", author: "$author", created: "$created", updated: "$updated", title: "$title", targetId: "$targetId", text: "$text", legacyId: "$legacyId", favoriteFeatures: "$favoriteFeatures", suggestedImprovements: "$suggestedImprovements", thumbsUpDownCounter: "$thumbsUpDownCounter", ratings: "$ratings", averageRating: "$averageRating" }, commentsCount: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$comments.moderationStatus", "STATUS_REJECTED" ] }, 0, 1 ] } } } }, { $sort: { _id.created: -1 } } ] } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 106 locks(micros) r:22339823 reslen:1133 13143ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:06.846 [conn3428793] end connection 10.11.32.97:50953 (84 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:13.702 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.101:33466 #3429154 (85 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:13.702 [conn3429149] end connection 10.11.32.101:33464 (83 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:19.310 [conn3429115] command local.$cmd command: { collstats: "oplog.rs" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:201604 reslen:290 201ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:21.672 [conn3429151] command xrr.$cmd command: { aggregate: "VehicleReview", pipeline: [ { $match: { make: "hyundai", model: "sonata", year: "2013", moderationStatus: "STATUS_PASSED" } }, { $group: { _id: { _id: "$all" }, averageRating: { $avg: "$averageRating" } } } ] } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 79 locks(micros) r:27839288 reslen:91 14859ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:21.672 [conn3429152] command xrr.$cmd command: { aggregate: "VehicleReview", pipeline: [ { $match: { make: "honda", model: "accord", year: "2013", moderationStatus: "STATUS_PASSED" } }, { $group: { _id: { _id: "$all" }, averageRating: { $avg: "$averageRating" } } } ] } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 74 locks(micros) r:28227783 reslen:91 14859ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:22.931 [conn3429150] end connection 10.11.32.100:39276 (83 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:22.932 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.100:39278 #3429155 (85 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:23.691 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 12ms
Fri Oct 11 15:17:25.458 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.97:39816 #3429156 (85 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:25.592 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.98:59425 #3429157 (86 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:25.966 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.97:39817 #3429158 (87 connections now open)
Fri Oct 11 15:17:25.993 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.11.32.97:39818 #3429159 (88 connections now open)
tcmalloc: large alloc 51539607552 bytes == (nil) @
Fri Oct 11 15:17:34.216 out of memory, printing stack and exiting:
0xdc7f71 0x6cd2ae 0x11fa48d 0xaf4a4f 0xaf0e8f 0xaf17ad 0xaf189f 0xaec46e 0xaec589 0xaea92e 0xaf82e8 0xaf8549 0xae3530 0xae39ef 0xaf0b2f 0xaf17c6 0xaf189f 0xb168c0 0x8a0ad2 0x8cd0ca
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdc7f71]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14my_new_handlerEv+0x3e) [0x6cd2ae]
/usr/bin/mongod(_Znwm+0x6d) [0x11fa48d]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZNSt6vectorIN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort9KeyAndDocESaIS2_EE7reserveEm+0x6f) [0xaf4a4f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort12populateTopKEv+0x6f) [0xaf0e8f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort8populateEv+0x2d) [0xaf17ad]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort3eofEv+0xf) [0xaf189f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSkip7skipperEv+0x6e) [0xaec46e]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSkip3eofEv+0x9) [0xaec589]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21DocumentSourceProject3eofEv+0xe) [0xaea92e]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceUnwind8lazyInitEv+0x138) [0xaf82e8]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo20DocumentSourceUnwind3eofEv+0x9) [0xaf8549]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup8populateEv+0x30) [0xae3530]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup3eofEv+0xf) [0xae39ef]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort11populateAllEv+0x2f) [0xaf0b2f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort8populateEv+0x46) [0xaf17c6]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18DocumentSourceSort3eofEv+0xf) [0xaf189f]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Pipeline3runERNS_14BSONObjBuilderERSs+0x1d0) [0xb168c0]
/usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15PipelineCommand3runERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x132) [0x8a0ad2]
?out /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x3a) [0x8cd0ca]
```

Comment: did you give a large  $limit parameter in your any query?

Answer (score 2):

There are 150 bug fixes between 2.4.1 and 2.4.6 (current minor release of 2.4 as of writing this answer).  You can see the full list [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/?jql=project%20=%20SERVER%20AND%20fixVersion%20in%20%28%222.4.2%22,%20%222.4.3%22,%20%222.4.4%22,%20%222.4.5%22,%20%222.4.6%22%29%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Resolved,%20closed%29%20ORDER%20BY%20component%20ASC,%20priority%20DESC).

There are several that might apply:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9213
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9230

But, they are not specific to the type of query you were running (although possible there are others contributing elsewhere).  There is also this bue, which still hits 2.4.6, and applies to the aggregation framework (running into the preceding stack trace to the crash):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10554

Hence, I would try testing [2.4.7-rc0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/KQASrSgJeOQ) (or 2.4.7+ once those releases are available) to see if that eliminates your issues.